# How can you debug server-hosted Blazor WASM code behind files in Visual Studio?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a hosted Blazor WASM application but can't hit any breakpoints in the code behind files. The code runs, just no break points get hit. If the same code is in an `@code { }` block in the razor file then the breakpoints get hit. Is there anything special that I need to do?

Comment: I use Vs 2019 v16.8.4 and  enabling "Enable Expermintal Razor editor" option and I can debug in the code behind and debugger stop on the breakpoint.

Comment: Also try installing the VS 2019 Preview, it should be a bit ahead in this type of features so it might work better.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue is only happening when using a Radzen Blazor Component. I opened an [issue here](https://github.com/radzenhq/radzen-blazor/issues/35).